# how to convert translate()[0] to d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to convert following code to d3 v4

```
let x = this.d3Zoom.translate()[0] - this.d3xScale(this.minHz) + this.d3xScale.range()[0];
this.d3Zoom.translate([x, 0]);
```

How do you perform translate()[0] in d3 v4?

Answer (score 1):

The d3 zoom functionality was [heavily modified](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/4/CHANGES.md#zooming-d3-zoom) from v3 to v4.   The big change being:

> Zoom behaviors no longer store the active zoom transform (i.e., the
>   visible region; the scale and translate) internally. The zoom
>   transform is now stored on any elements to which the zoom behavior has
>   been applied.

That said, you haven't posted enough code to really tell what you are attempting **but** if you are inside a zoom event handler, you would use:

```
event.transform.x
```

If you are outside a zoom event handler, then you need to get this from the node where the zoom is being applied:

```
d3.zoomTransform(node).transform.x
```